# How to take the max value of a series when using pandas Grouper?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
U_ID     Group   Location  Hours  People  Date
149      17      USA       2      2       2014-11-03
149      17      USA       2      1       2014-11-07
149      21      USA       3      2       2014-12-21
149      18      UK        1.5    1       2014-11-14
149      19      Spain     2      4       2014-11-21
```

Which I can rollup the number of hours with the following code snippet:

```
def process_hours(hr_df):
    hr_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(hr_df['Date'])
    hr_df['Hours'] = pd.to_numeric(hr_df['Hours'])
    hr_df = (vol_df.groupby(['U_ID', 'Group', 'Location', 'People', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='MS')])['Hours'].sum().reset_index(level=[0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

However this splits when the number of people differ:

```
           U_ID Group Location People  Hours
Date                                        
2014-11-01  149    17      USA      1    2.0
2014-11-01  149    17      USA      2    2.0
2014-11-01  149    18       UK      1    1.5
2014-11-01  149    19    Spain      4    2.0
2014-12-01  149    21      USA      2    3.0
```

How do I take the max number of people when the grouping happens to result in this:

```
           U_ID Group Location People  Hours
Date                                        
2014-11-01  149    17      USA      2    4.0
2014-11-01  149    18       UK      1    1.5
2014-11-01  149    19    Spain      4    2.0
2014-12-01  149    21      USA      2    3.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove "People" from the grouper and use `agg` to specify `groupby` to additionally take the `max` of people.

```
(hr_df.groupby(['U_ID', 'Group', 'Location', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='MS')])
      .agg({'Hours' : 'sum', 'People' : 'max'})
      .reset_index()  # Don't hardcode levels here.
      .set_index('Date'))

            U_ID  Group Location  Hours  People
Date                                           
2014-11-01   149     17      USA    4.0       2
2014-11-01   149     18       UK    1.5       1
2014-11-01   149     19    Spain    2.0       4
2014-12-01   149     21      USA    3.0       2
```

The reason I recommend not hardcoding levels here is for better maintainability. Using `reset_index(level=[0, 1, 2])` is more performant than `reset_index` + `set_index`. However, for example, if you decide to add another column to the grouper, you'll need to modify the reset index call... which is fine and dandy. If you want more easily maintainable code, consider not hardcoding them.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with specify columns names with aggregation functions in dictionary:

```
hr_df = (hr_df.groupby(['U_ID', 'Group', 'Location', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='MS')])
              .agg({'Hours':'sum', 'People':'max'})
              .reset_index(level=[0, 1, 2])
              )
print (hr_df)
            U_ID  Group Location  Hours  People
Date                                           
2014-11-01   149     17      USA    4.0       2
2014-11-01   149     18       UK    1.5       1
2014-11-01   149     19    Spain    2.0       4
2014-12-01   149     21      USA    3.0       2
```

Comment: It's the same code as mine but fixes the mistake I made wrt to Date as the index, right?

Comment: Today their code says `.reset_index(level=[0, 1, 2, 3])`, now your answer will change it to `.reset_index(level=[0, 1, 2])`. Tomorrow if they add another column to the grouper, it will become `.reset_index(level=[0, 1, 2, 3])` again. Performance is one thing but performance isn't everything. Maintainability counts.

Comment: Fair enough. Feel free to argue your case as well. It's up to OP to decide which they prefer. Obviously there is no single answer here.

Comment: There's a difference between making a suggestion in an answer and saying "don't use that other guy's answer, it's not good". I think you're overanalysing things here. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, now it is much better.